# Low bandwidth with multi-threaded httpWebRequest

Tags: multithreading, httpwebrequest, bandwidth

I've a wcf service that call a webservice asynchronously using httpwebrequest.beginGetResponse(). My problem is that when I call it from another service using TPL (max concurrency : 300), my bandwidth downed and impossible to connect to internet.
Does anyone have a good solution to limit this bad effect? I already tried to configure in the config

```
<connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="2000" />
</connectionManagement>
```

but this doesn't work

Thanks to your help

Comment: Maybe trying to make hundreds of connections isn't such a good idea.

Comment: this was only an example copy-paste from the web... I set it to 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it...
In my wcf service, I replace

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

with

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

Now that's work fine. Who have an explanation?